# How do I create monthly auto billing by different amount in paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I am building advertise server using **CodeIgnitor**.

I am going to receive money per month automatically.

The monthly amount is different by the number that ads click.

So I have authorized user's paypal once user signup and got user's information.

But I can not receive monthly amount without user's agreement.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use ordinary payment methods use subscription payment  method
Refer the documentation

[paypal subscription documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#2-create-a-product)